# Javascript: automatical horizontal scrolling

Tags: javascript

I have a simple javascript code that automatically scrolls the div element horizontaly.

Is there any option how to make it smoother and more effective? I have code where same parts are repeating and that's not good.

I'm trying to make smooth scrolling without any cuts.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
        document.querySelector("div").scrollLeft = 50;
    },2000);
  
  setTimeout(function() {
        document.querySelector("div").scrollLeft = 100;
    },4000);
  
    
  setTimeout(function() {
        document.querySelector("div").scrollLeft = 150;
    },6000);
```

```css
p {
width: 2000px;
}

div {
overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque consequuntur quas libero voluptatem recusandae necessitatibus inventore, velit aperiam, incidunt ut eos distinctio, ducimus magnam veritatis tenetur autem debitis iusto dolorum?</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a short `setInterval()` to smoothly scroll the div:

```js
var boo = document.getElementById("boo");
function move() {
  boo.scrollLeft += 1;
}
setInterval(move, 20)
```

```css
p {
width: 2000px;
}

div {
overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="boo">
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque consequuntur quas libero voluptatem recusandae necessitatibus inventore, velit aperiam, incidunt ut eos distinctio, ducimus magnam veritatis tenetur autem debitis iusto dolorum?</p>
</div>
```